# How to mock a Stream response when calling HttpClient GetStreamAsync

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq

I'm trying to test a class that uses HttpClient and i have to fake the Stream response.

This is the code i'm trying to test.

```
            try
            {
                _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _credentials);

                using (Stream s = _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(API_string).Result)  <---- this is the trouble line.
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                    return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader); //breaks loop
                }
            }
```

From the test side, i can insert my custom HttpClientHandler and send back any response i want.

This is my Fake HttpClientHandler builder (I'm using Moq).

```
    public HttpClientHandler MockHttpClientHandler()
    {
        var requestUri = new Uri("Uri.Expected.To.Be.Called");
        var expectedResponse = "Response text"; <-- This is where i need to write the Object to be returned.

        var mockResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(expectedResponse) };
        var mockHandler = new Mock<HttpClientHandler>();
        mockHandler
            .Protected()
            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                "SendAsync",
                ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(message => message.RequestUri == requestUri),
                // ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
                ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockResponse));

        return mockHandler.Object;
    }
```

My test breaks when it tries to run the return line, because whatever i'm sending back can't be deserialized. I just don't know what my Stream s should look like, and i can't see its contents by debugging either.

I'm fairly lost here. Maybe my approach is wrong?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: what do you mean by it breaks? does it throw an exception, does an assertion fail? if so what are you asserting?

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but there is a library out there that has something called RestClient. It wraps HttpClient and whilst giving various performance benefits, it also introduces an interface IRestClient that means you can test things much easier as you can then mock the client you're self. Obviously requires a new dependency or some external code brought in and changing you interface but it might be worth a look. It can be found in here https://github.com/NimaAra/Easy.Common/tree/master/Easy.Common

Comment: To me it looks like you are testing the .net classes (and that would be the job for Microsoft) - what behavior of your code is it that you want to test?

Comment: Once i fetch that data, its sent back to the main method requesting the Http calls, and then this data is handled. The thing is that the method making the Http calls is generic, and its used multiple times, so i got to fake each of those different kind of calls.

Comment: @Dave how to set Authorization in RestClient ? 
because defaultRequestHeaders type is as follow.
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> defaultRequestHeaders = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>()

to be set.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

Answer (score 3):

```
        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StreamContent(stream)
        };

        var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
        handlerMock
            .Protected()
            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                  "SendAsync",
                  ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
                  ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
           .ReturnsAsync(httpResponse);
```